# Mapstruct is unable to map into multiple levels of nested objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm using MapStruct version 1.4.2, Java 17 and Spring-boot 3.1.0.
Here I'm trying to map into a nested object by passing source to the mapper method as below.

```
public class PackageProgress { 
    private Sender sender;
}

public class Sender {
    private Client client;
}

public class Client {
    private Integer childClientId;
    private ClientCacheData clientCacheData;
}

public class ClientCacheData {
    private String clientName;
    private String clientAddress;
}

public class ClientData {
    private String clientName;
    private String clientAddress;
}

public class PackageGateway {

    private final ClientDataCache clientDataCache;
    private final ParcelConnector connector;
    private final PackageMapper packageMapper;
    public Mono<PackageProgress> getUserById(ResolvedPackageId uid) {
        return connector.getById(uid)
           .map(parcel -> {
               ClientData clientData = clientDataCache.getClientDetails(parcel.getClientId(), parcel.getChildClientId());
               PackageProgress packageProgress = packageMapper.from(parcel, uid, clientData);
               return packageProgress;
          });
    }

}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = UrlMapper.class)
public interface PackageMapper {

    PackageMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PackageMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "sender", source = "parcel")
    @Mapping(target = "sender.client.clientCacheData", source = "clientData")
    PackageProgress from(ParcelDto parcel, ResolvedPackageId uid, ClientData clientData);

    @Mapping(target = "childClientId", source = "childClientId", defaultValue = "0")
    Client clientFrom(ParcelDto parcel);

    @Mapping(target = "client", source = "parcel")
    Sender senderFrom(ParcelDto parcel);

}
```

But when I introduced new mapping `@Mapping(target = "sender.client.clientCacheData", source = "clientData")` end up having below errors.

```
java: No read accessor found for property "sender" in target type.
java: No target bean properties found: can't map property "ParcelDto parcel" to "Sender sender". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "Sender map(ParcelDto value)".
java: Unknown property "client" in type Sender for target name "sender.client.clientCacheData". Did you mean "sender.client"?
```

Is this nested mapping scenario not possible using `@Mapping`?
What could be missing here?

Comment: @Sören my mistake, yes.